# What fields can be used for an inner product space?

Tags: fields, inner-product, ordered-fields

The title is the question: What fields can be used for an inner product space?

This question has been discussed in Math Stack Exchange with no definitive resolution.  A similar question appeared here, and an answer was accepted, but someone pointed out a serious problem with the answer.

I am using the standard definition of inner product, which includes $\langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x} \rangle > 0$ for all non zero vectors $\mathbf{x}$.

It seems to me that any field of prime characteristic does not make sense, because it does not have an order relation that respects addition.  It also seems to me that the field $\mathbb{F}$ can be any ordered field or any subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ that is stable under complex conjugation (for any non-algebraists like me, the word "stable" seems to be standard here. Anyone else would use the word "closed").  I do not know if any other fields are possible.  Of course, an ordered field may or may not be a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$.

It seems to be rare for people, even mathematicians, to use any field other than $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ for an inner product space.

Can anyone clear this up?

EDIT: Mark Grant [alerted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129413/what-fields-can-be-used-for-an-inner-product-space#comment333476_129413) me to a Wikipedia page that addresses this question (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition).  Let me quote the relevant part :
"There are various technical reasons why it is necessary to restrict the basefield to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ in the definition. Briefly, the basefield has to contain an ordered subfield[citation needed] (in order for non-negativity to make sense) and therefore has to have characteristic equal to 0 (since any ordered field has to have such characteristic). This immediately excludes finite fields. The basefield has to have additional structure, such as a distinguished automorphism. More generally any quadratically closed subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ will suffice for this purpose, e.g., the algebraic numbers…."

The Wikipedia article fails to explain why the basefield has to have additional structure.  They do not define a "distinguished automorphism" or provide a link to a definition.  I am not an algebraist.  I Googled the term and I could not find a definition of "distinguished automorphism".  I did find links to papers and books that probably do contain a definition.  The article states it is "necessary" to restrict the basefield to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ in the definition but then contradicts itself by at least suggesting that the basefield can be  any quadratically closed subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Doesn't the wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition go a long way towards clearing this up?

Comment: One could easily define an inner product for a vector space over a *formally real field* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formally_real_field ... Your condition would then be $\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\rangle \ne 0$ for nonzero vectors $\mathbf x$. 

Comment: @Mark Grant : not really.  I have read that article several times and I just looked at it again.  They seem to use only $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ until they discuss "generalizations", of inner product spaces , and I am not interested in generalizations.

Comment: @Stefan: I was referring to the second paragraph of the "Remark" at the end of the "Definition" section, which discusses exactly this point. 

Comment: @Gerald : thanks, I never heard of a "formally real field".  I read the link, and it does not explain whether there is any difference between "formally real field" and "ordered field", that is, it is unclear whether there exists a field that belongs to one class and not the other.  In addition, I want to keep the requirement $\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\rangle > 0$ for all nonzero vectors $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: @Mark Grant : Thanks.  I guess I didn't read the Wikipedia article closely enough.  The article is helpful but not 100% satisfactory.  I edited my question.

Comment: In the Hermitian case "field" is overly restrictive (the skew field of quaternions is important too).  Even in the symmetric case, it can be convenient to look at rings: for example, integral lattices are often thought of as free abelian groups with integer-valued, positive-definite, symmetric bilinear forms.  (Of course integers are real numbers, so this can be thought of as a special case of real inner products, but the restriction to a subring changes how things feel.)  

Comment: It's also worth keeping in mind that people often look at analogues of symmetric and even Hermitian inner products in cases without positive definiteness.  (For example, to define unitary groups over finite fields.)  This is certainly somewhat different from the real/complex/quaternionic case, but it's not like there's a sharp dividing line conceptually.  Instead, you just give up more properties.

Comment: Stefan: Any rational function field over $\mathbb R$ in a finitely many variables (for example, $\mathbb R\left(x,y\right)$) is formally real (for rather simple reasons: if you had some rational functions whose squares sum up to $-1$, you could substitute values into them in such a way that the denominators don't vanish, so you'd get a sum of real squares summing up to $-1$, which is absurd), while not being totally ordered in a natural way (unless it has $0$ variables). I don't know if it can be ordered in non-natural ways, but this already shows that the two definitions aren't the same.

Comment: Also, $\mathbb Q\left[\sqrt 2\right]$ can be ordered in two ways (by making $\sqrt 2$ negative and by making $\sqrt 2$ positive), neither of which is "better" than the other. This already shows that it isn't a good idea to identify "formally real" with "ordered" because the latter requires a choice of ordering while the former does not.

Comment: @darij : Thanks.  Apparently "ordered field" refers to a field _together with the order relation_ while a "formally real" field is a field that _can be endowed with_ an order relation with the required properties.  I don't really understand your first comment.  I don't see an obvious order relation for formal real-valued rational functions in real variables $x$ and $y$ similar to the standard order relation for rational functions in just $x$.

Comment: @darij: regarding your first comment, I just reread Wikipedia's article on formally real fields and they mention an alternative definition concerning $-1$ being a sum of squares, so I understand your first comment now.

Comment: @Gerald : regarding your suggestion, if we take a formally real field, we can just impose an order on it and make it an ordered field.  Why can't we keep the condition $\langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x} \rangle > 0$ for nonzero $\mathbf{x}$?  And do we have the "additional structure" that wikipedia says we need (please see my edited question)?

Comment: @Stefan: Because the order is in general not unique. In order for the condition to make sense, you have to fix a particular order, but then you can as well come out and say that the structure you are working with is an ordered field, rather than just a formally real field. By the way, the order on a formally real field is unique if and only if every element or its negation can be written as a sum of squares, but I don’t know if such fields have a special name.

Comment: To extend the answer of wikipedia: if $\mathbb{F}$ admits a conjugate $*$ (which may be just doing nothing), you can replace $\langle x,x \rangle \gt 0$ with $\langle x,x \rangle =a^*a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{F}$. So if $*$ does nothing, it must be a square (example: finite fields). This is the $C^*$-algebra definition of positive.

Comment: It would have been better, had OP linked to the previous discussions, instead of just mentioning their existence.

Answer (score 8):

Of course if you insist on condition $\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\rangle > 0$, and not merely $\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\rangle \ne 0$, then you must have an order.

Let $F$ be a formally real field.  Then
$$
\langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\rangle = \sum_{j=1}^n x_j y_j
$$
can be a reasonable inner product on $F^n$.  According to an ordering for $F$ (indeed, any ordering, since there may be more than one) we have $\langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}\rangle > 0$ if $\mathbf x \ne \mathbf 0$.

Another part that you quote is what would be required for metric completeness.    Do you want that? If $F$ is a proper subfield of $\mathbb R$, then even the one-dimensional space is not complete.

Something weaker than completeness will be enough to carry out the Gram-Schmidt process.  It requires only that square-roots of $\langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}\rangle$ exist.

Comment: @Gerald : Thanks.  I don't really care about metric completeness for this question.  Either I forgot to omit that part from the Wikipedia quote, or someone put it back in. What about the mysterious  "additional structure, such as a distinguished automorphism", that the Wikipedia article refers to? Do we need to impose that, is it there already, or is the article wrong?  

Comment: I think that the additional structure is supposed to be complex conjugation. Recall that a Hermitian inner product changes by conjugation when you swap its arguments. So you might allow yourself the freedom to pick some map from the field to itself to play the role of complex conjugation.

Comment: @Gerald:  I don't even care for this question whether square roots of $\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\rangle$ exist, or whether you can carry out the Gram-Schmidt process, just the basic definition of inner product (with positive-definiteness).

Comment: Orthogonal bases are useful enough and perhaps you are happy with them not being of normalized vectors. You may run Gram-Schmidt without normalization and I think you don't need square roots of positive elements for that. 

Comment: @Franklin : good observation.

Comment: @Gerald : You make a convincing argument that any formally real field $\mathbb{F}$ will work.  But I would like something more general, that includes Hermitian inner products.  Perhaps, we need a field $\mathbb{F}$ with an ordered subfield $\mathbb{F}_1 \subset \mathbb{F}$ and a field automorphism $\phi: \mathbb{F} \to \mathbb{F}$ such that $\mathbf{x}\phi(\mathbf{x}) \in \mathbb{F}_1$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{F}$ and $\mathbf{x}\phi(\mathbf{x}) > 0$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{F} \setminus \{0\}$.  Does anyone know if that is good enough?  Is it too much? 

Answer (score 2):

The positive definiteness axiom can be replaced with an axiom asserting the existence of an "orthonormal basis".

Let $R$ be a $*$-ring. We consider a left $*$-module over $R$ which we call $M$. We ask what it means for a Hermitian form $\langle -, - \rangle$ to be an inner product over $M$.

In finite dimensions, you would say that $\langle -, - \rangle$ is an inner product if there exists a finite basis $B=\{b_1,b_2,\dotsc,b_n\}$ of $M$ such that $\langle b_i, b_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$ where we have used the Kronecker delta symbol.

In possibly infinite dimensions, you would ask that your "orthonormal basis" only be "densely spanning". What I mean by this is that there should exist a subset $B \subset M$ for which $\langle b, b' \rangle=\begin{cases}1, & b = b' \\ 0, & b \neq b' \end{cases}$, and for which every $0 \neq v \in M$ should admit some $b \in B$ for which $\langle b, v \rangle \neq 0$.

For the usual $*$-rings of $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ (with their usual involutions) this recovers the usual notion of an inner product space. The proof uses Zorn's Lemma.

In foundations not admitting the Axiom of Choice, this definition may be superior to the usual one. It's certainly easier to do maths over an inner product space once you have an orthonormal basis.

---

In answer to your question, the appropriate setting is $*$-fields, and not fields. And all $*$-fields can admit inner product spaces.

Comment: It seems that, at least in finite dimensions, the datum of "vector space with specified orthonormal basis" is little more than "vector space with basis":  if I just have a basis, then it is orthonormal for an appropriate inner product (at least if we agree that the ground $*$-field supports inner products).  So what do I gain by calling the basis orthonormal rather than just a basis?  Or, perhaps stated differently, what do I gain by restricting my attention to these sorts of ground $*$-fields?

Comment: @LSpice It's not a "vector space with specified basis", it's actually a vector space and a Hermitian form which admits *some* basis which is orthonormal with respect to it. The point being, that given an inner product, there may be *lots* of bases which are orthonormal with respect to it, and we don't care which one it is.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "*these sorts* of ground $*$-fields". I'm suggesting that you can use any and all $*$-fields whatsoever. There are still unique advantages though to $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb H$ (equipped with their usual involutions), as expressed by [Solèr's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sol%C3%A8r%27s_theorem).

Comment: @LSpice I've read your comment and I still don't understand it. I think you've misunderstood something in what I said. Can you clarify?

Comment: You seemed to propose "VS with Hermitian form that admits an orthonormal basis".  I am saying that, even if we strengthen that to "VS with a Hermitian form *and* a preferred orthonormal basis", then it seems that we are doing nothing more than specifying an abstract vector space with a preferred basis, because you can recover the Hermitian form from the basis and "sequilinearity".  So it seems at first that anything one could prove about general vector spaces with Hermitian forms using orthonormal bases could be proven about bare vector spaces using bases, and I am asking why that's not so.

Comment: As to "these sorts of ground $*$-fields", I misspoke; I meant "these sorts of coefficient rings" (since Hermitian-ness either doesn't make sense, or is just bilinearity, depending on how one interprets it, over a general ground ring), where "these sort" means "$*$-fields".

Comment: @LSpice If you fix a vector space $V$, and consider different bases and inner products over it, then different bases can give rise to the same inner product, while some bases might give rise to differing inner products over $V$. Your suggestion might introduce notational clutter. Also, you'll need to use the inner product operation to define analogues of unitary morphisms, Hermitian morphisms and projections. Similarly, you need it to construct a $\dagger$-category. Also, in the non-finitely generated case, the "orthogonal basis" actually doesn't form a basis, so the term is only suggestive.